# Using caching in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, caching, webview

I have been searching for days for a good caching solution for my WebView app. The solutions I find don't seem to work for me. Me being new at making apps along with the changes on caching that deprecates many older solutions seems to be hampering me.

Essentially, what I have is a large WebView with a row of buttons on the bottom navigation changing the URL of the WebView. I would like pages that were already loaded previously to load from cache. This should be the default behavior of the WebView, but it doesn't seem to be loading faster (it should be almost instant right?). I would also like the WebView to load from the cache if the network is unavailable.

This is a snippet of the code I have so far with my previous attempts at caching removed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    my_web_view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view); //grab a handle on the web wrapper

    //set all of our variables for use later
    home_URL = "https://akvcoc.com/app-home";
    events_URL = "https://akvcoc.com/app-events";
    directory_URL = "https://akvcoc.ctrn.co/directory/index.php";

    my_web_view.loadUrl(home_URL);                    //set the web wrapper to the home page

    my_web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);              //and set javascript to true

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                my_web_view.loadUrl(home_URL);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_events:
                my_web_view.loadUrl(events_URL);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_directory:
                my_web_view.loadUrl(directory_URL);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you use javascript in you Website

Comment: Yes, I could use javascript in the website. The web pages being loaded are managed by the guy I am working with on this project.

Comment: Can you explain what is your exact problem?

Comment: I would like the webview to cache the pages the app's buttons go to, but it doesn't seem to do so.  Each time you click on a button, it takes the same amount of time to load the page.  Also, if I terminate wifi and cellular data after having loaded the page once, it won't go to the page even though it should have the data cached.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't looked at this post for a while.  I was debating whether I would build the entire thing native or continue using the web view.  We decided to stick with the webview.  Anyone that could help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You add this line to load javascript in webview.

```
my_web_view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```